# Ansible fails installing IIS Web-Server on virtualbox windows machine

Tags: windows, virtualbox, active-directory, iis, ansible

I am trying to install Active Directory Labratory [GOAD](https://github.com/Orange-Cyberdefense/GOAD) to practice and get familiar with active directory. I use ansible-core 2.2.16, virtualbox 6.1 and vagrant 2.2.19 to install it.

The lab uses a bash for automating installation installing boxes and playing ansible books, and every thing goes fine up to  the `TASK [iis : Install IIS Web-Server with sub features and management tools]` with error `fatal: [srv02]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to install Windows Feature: The request to add or remove features on the specified server failed.\r\nInstallation of one or more roles, role services, or features failed. Error: 0x80072f8f\n"}`. I searched a lot but couldn't find anything helpful. can anyone help me?

This is the [ansible-playbook](https://github.com/Orange-Cyberdefense/GOAD/blob/main/ansible/servers.yml) that causes error with this [inventory](https://github.com/Orange-Cyberdefense/GOAD/blob/main/ad/GOAD-Light/providers/virtualbox/inventory) file.

The automation process is implemented in [goad.sh](https://github.com/Orange-Cyberdefense/GOAD/blob/main/goad.sh) file that I run using command `./goad.sh -t install -l GOAD-Light -p virtualbox -m local`